# Ext JS handling events in a single place

Tags: extjs, globalevent

So I have and Ext js application and in my application launch function at the bottom, after I draw components there is the next line of code:

```
Ext.ComponentManager.all.on('render', function(cmp) { console.log(cmp); });
```

I expect that all components go through this function before being rendered to user but it's not. can you give any suggestions what can be happening? Anyway, what I want to do is to catch `render` or `beforerender` event of all components in a single place. yeah my application uses MVC architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you can add listeners for these events to all components using `*` as the component query:

```
this.control({
    '*': {
        beforerender: function(cmp) {
            console.log('beforerender: ' + cmp.id);
        },
        render: function(cmp) {
            console.log('render: ' + cmp.id);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I would have to do that in all controllers yes? Is not there any other place? Thanks anyway for suggestion.

Comment: It should be enough to do that in one controller, as the [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) is applied globally.